# Python regex unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, regex

```
str1='<a href="/states/florida/433" title="florida"><img alt="florida" src="http://abc.com"'
str2='<a href="/states/florida/433" title="florida">'
pat = re.compile('/states/.*/([^"]+)')
if ( pat.findall(str2) == pat.findall(str1)):
    print "TRUE"
else:
    print "FALSE"
```

OUTPUT: FALSE,

output2: 433 
output1: abc.com

Can somebody explain?

Comment: What's strange?  Your RegEx is working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use reluctant quantifier - `.*?`, instead of greedy one - `.*` and all will be well: -

```
pat = re.compile('/states/.*?/([^"]+)')
```

Quantifiers are by default *greedy*, in the sense they try to cover as much string as they can, and still leaving the rest of the pattern to match the remaining string. Using `?` after the quantifier makes it *reluctant*, in which case, they will stop at the first match of the following character - `/` in this case.

Comment: Additionally, I'd say to not use `.*` here at all. Use the regex to say what a state-name looks like too so that you know what you're grabbing before you grab it

Answer (score 1):

On the first URL, your regexp matches the whole string :

```
<a href="/states/florida/433" title="florida"><img alt="florida" src="http://abc.com
         /states/                                .*                         /([^"]+)
```

and not

```
<a href="/states/florida/433" title="florida"><img alt="florida" src="http://abc.com
         /states/ .*   /([^"])+
```

They are greedy and `.*` eats as much data as it can.

Answer (score 1):

Your RegEx is working properly:

```
<a href="/states/florida/433" title="florida"><img alt="florida" src="http://abc.com"
         ^^^^^^^^............................................................^^^^^^^
         /states/                      .*/                                     [^"]+
```

And:

```
<a href="/states/florida/433" title="florida">
         ^^^^^^^^........^^^
```

If you don't want to consume the whole string in the first case, use `?`, the non-greedy matching quantifier to say "`/states/` followed by any number of characters up until *the first* `/` followed by one or more non-quote characters"

Answer (score 0):

You're pattern is greedy (you can read about greedy and non greedy regex patterns here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html and here: http://www.itworld.com/nl/perl/01112001.  Changing the pattern from

```
'/states/.*/([^"]+)'
```

to

```
'/states/.*/([^"]+)'
```

returns true.  Here's the full modified source:

```
import re

str1='<a href="/states/florida/433" title="florida"><img alt="florida" src="http://abc.com"'
str2='<a href="/states/florida/433" title="florida">'
pat = re.compile('/states/.*?/([^"]+)')
if ( pat.findall(str2) == pat.findall(str1)):
    print "TRUE"
else:
    print "FALSE"
```